# Combining IRanges objects and maintaining mcols

Tags: r, iranges

I'll start with an example, and then describe the logic I'm trying to use.

I have two normal `IRanges` objects that span the same total range, but may do so in a different number of ranges.  Each `IRanges` has one `mcol`, but that `mcol` is different across `IRanges`.

```
a
#IRanges object with 1 range and 1 metadata column:
#          start       end     width | on_betalac
#      <integer> <integer> <integer> |  <logical>
#  [1]         1       167       167 |      FALSE
b
#IRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#          start       end     width |  on_other
#      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <logical>
#  [1]         1       107       107 |     FALSE
#  [2]       108       112         5 |      TRUE
#  [3]       113       167        55 |     FALSE
```

You can see both of these `IRanges` span 1 to 167, but `a` has one range and `b` has three.  I would like to combine them to get output like this:

```
my_great_function(a, b)
#IRanges object with 3 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
#          start       end     width | on_betalac  on_other
#      <integer> <integer> <integer> |  <logical> <logical>
#  [1]         1       107       107 |     FALSE     FALSE
#  [2]       108       112         5 |     FALSE      TRUE
#  [3]       113       167        55 |     FALSE     FALSE
```

The output is a like a `disjoin` of the inputs, but it keeps the `mcols`, and even spreads them so that the output range has the same value of the `mcol` as the input range that led to it.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: Using `IRanges::findOverlaps`

```
m <- findOverlaps(b, a)
c <- b[queryHits(m)]
mcols(c) <- cbind(mcols(c), mcols(a[subjectHits(m)]))
#IRanges object with 3 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
#          start       end     width |  on_other on_betacalc
#      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <logical>   <logical>
#  [1]         1       107       107 |     FALSE       FALSE
#  [2]       108       112         5 |      TRUE       FALSE
#  [3]       113       167        55 |     FALSE       FALSE
```

The resulting object `c` is a `IRanges` object with two metadata columns.

### Option 2: Using `IRanges::mergeByOverlaps`

```
c <- mergeByOverlaps(b, a)
c
#DataFrame with 3 rows and 4 columns
#          b  on_other         a on_betacalc
#  <IRanges> <logical> <IRanges>   <logical>
#1     1-107     FALSE     1-167       FALSE
#2   108-112      TRUE     1-167       FALSE
#3   113-167     FALSE     1-167       FALSE
```

The resulting output object is a `DataFrame` with `IRanges` columns and original metadata columns as additional columns.

### Option 3: Using `data.table::foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)
a.dt <- as.data.table(cbind.data.frame(a, mcols(a)))[, width := NULL]
b.dt <- as.data.table(cbind.data.frame(b, mcols(b)))[, width := NULL]

setkey(b.dt, start, end)
foverlaps(a.dt, b.dt, type = "any")[, `:=`(i.start = NULL, i.end = NULL)][]
   start end on_other on_betacalc
1:     1 107    FALSE       FALSE
2:   108 112     TRUE       FALSE
3:   113 167    FALSE       FALSE
```

The resulting object is a `data.table`.

### Option 4: Using `fuzzyjoin::interval_left_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
a.df <- cbind.data.frame(a, mcols(a))
b.df <- cbind.data.frame(b, mcols(b))
interval_left_join(b.df, a.df, by = c("start", "end"))
#  start.x end.x width.x on_other start.y end.y width.y on_betacalc
#1       1   107     107    FALSE       1   167     167       FALSE
#2     108   112       5     TRUE       1   167     167       FALSE
#3     113   167      55    FALSE       1   167     167       FALSE
```

The resulting object is a `data.frame`.

---

### Sample data

```
library(IRanges)
a <- IRanges(1, 167)
mcols(a)$on_betacalc = F

b <- IRanges(c(1, 108, 113), c(107, 112, 167))
mcols(b)$on_other <- c(F, T, F)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems very promising, especially option 1.  I am now considering a situation with more than two IRanges as input.  Would that be a simple extension of option #1 or should I make a new SO question?

Comment: You're very welcome @rcorty; yes, merging more than 2 `IRanges` is a bit more challenging; I remember answering a similar question here on SO a while back, perhaps take some time searching for related questions here (and on Biostars/SeqAnswers). The order of the merge will matter in the case of 3 `IRanges`; obviously you're welcome to ask a new question, best to include reproducible sample data with `dput` (which means that we don't have to manually construct sample data like I did here).

Comment: [continued] As to the different options I give above: They all give you the same result, so there's really no major advantage of one solution over the other (mind you I haven't benchmarked the different options in terms of performance).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look through related questions.  I am very novice with IRanges.  The only reason #1 appeals to me is that the output is in precisely the format I want, so don't have to do any wrangling.  Can you comment on my proposed solution (below)?

Comment: @rcorty I guess you mean the solution you posted yourself? There seems to be a lot more data wrangling going on than in the options I posted. Simply `cbind`ing the metadata columns (as in option 1) should work for *any* number of metadata columns. I think the `for` loop plus `sapply` is not necessary and might make things very slow for larger `IRanges` objects. I imagine the `IRanges` options to be very fast; ditto for the `data.table` solution; the `fuzzyjoin::interval_join` is actually based on `IRanges::findOverlaps` so should be similarly performant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been able to come up with.  Not as elegant as MauritsEvers, but maybe useful to others in some way.

```
combine_exposures <- function(...) {

  cd <- c(...)
  mc <- mcols(cd)
  dj <- disjoin(x = cd, with.revmap = TRUE)
  r <- mcols(dj)$revmap

  d <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(dj), ncol = ncol(mc)))
  names(d) <- names(mc)

  for (i in 1:length(dj)) {
    d[i,] <- sapply(X = 1:ncol(mc), FUN = function(j) { mc[r[[i]][j], j] })
  }

  mcols(dj) <- d
  return(dj)
}
```

here is `dput(c(e1, e2, e3, e4))` (e1, e2, e3, and e4 are some example IRanges that all span 1,167):

```
new("IRanges", start = c(1L, 1L, 108L, 113L, 1L, 1L), width = c(167L, 
107L, 5L, 55L, 167L, 167L), NAMES = NULL, elementType = "ANY", 
    elementMetadata = new("DataFrame", rownames = NULL, nrows = 6L, 
        listData = list(on_betalac = c(FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), on_other = c(NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA), on_pen = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA), on_quin = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        FALSE)), elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, 
        metadata = list()), metadata = list())
```